# MySQL 8 SELECT FOR UPDATE locks all matching rows when using order by, even if transaction isolation is set to READ COMMITTED

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora, mysql-8.0

I'm trying to optimise a query for a queue processing app which stores and retrieves data based on filter conditions from a mysql 8 database. Ideally I want to lock a single row and allocate it to a worker process.

Currently I'm doing something like :

```sql
START TRANSACTION;
SET TRANSACTION isolation level READ COMMITTED; 

SELECT * FROM queue 
WHERE state = "free" and <other conditions> 
ORDER BY updatedAt ASC 
LIMIT 1 
FOR UPDATE 
SKIP LOCKED

UPDATE queue SET state = "processing" , updatedAt = ? WHERE id = ? 
COMMIT;
```

This fetches an free row from the database and sets it to processing so it wont be assigned to another worker.

The issue here is mysql takes a lock on all available rows which match the where conditions for the duration of the transaction. So another process requesting a free record in parallel wont be able to get it since the first transaction blocked all free records.
As per mysql docs, using [READ COMMITTED](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#:%7E:text=InnoDB%20Locking%E2%80%9D.-,READ%20COMMITTED,-Each%20consistent%20read) transaction isolation level should result in a single row being locked for the select for update query. This happens if I fire the above query without the order by statement, but using the order by statement causes it to lock all rows matching the where conditions.

I've considered a couple of ways to mitigate this, but none of them are ideal:

- Adding an index on updated_at : This is doable but not ideal. Will increase commit latency, plus I'll have to add indexes to any additional columns that require ordering in the future.
- Removing the order by clause: Can be done with some preprocessing, but lot more effort to implement using bucketing or something similar
- Other transaction isolation levels : More risky to implement properly

Is there any other way to avoid mysql blocking multiple rows for processing the above query

Comment: Your query is set to process the oldest (smallest `updatedAt`) row first. Is processing the oldest first a mandatory part of your application? Or can you process them in any order? That is, must you use `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Yes, I need to ensure the oldest row gets processed first. Have some approaches to avoid using the order by, but they are all not straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

*"As per mysql docs, using READ COMMITTED transaction isolation level should result in a single row being locked for the select for update query"* is actually not what the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html) says. The release of unmodified locks only applies to an actual `update`, not `select for update`:

> Using READ COMMITTED has additional effects:
>
> For UPDATE or DELETE statements, InnoDB holds locks only for rows that it updates or deletes. Record locks for nonmatching rows are released after MySQL has evaluated the WHERE condition. This greatly reduces the probability of deadlocks, but they can still happen.

What you are doing is a locking read, so specifically not a [consistent read](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-consistent-read.html) that that part of your documentation talks about:

> With READ COMMITTED isolation level, each consistent read within a transaction sets and reads its own fresh snapshot. **With FOR SHARE, a locking read occurs instead: A SELECT blocks until the transaction containing the freshest rows ends** (see [Section 15.7.2.4, “Locking Reads”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)).

So your behaviour is expected.

As you already mentioned, adding an index on `updatedAt` or maybe `(state, updatedAt)` should fix it. It will also make your select faster (as you have to read a lot less rows), which will probably counter any effect you think the "commit latency" costs, so I would at least test it. But there are of course other things to consider that only you know.

If you don't do anything else in your transaction (e.g. this transaction is relatively quick compared to what else the workers do), you may also want to consider just not using `skip lock` and letting the other workers wait a little longer to get their job.

Another alternative could be to use a non-locking select (you actually can do it without a transaction at all, if you like):

- do a non-locking

  ```
  SELECT ... WHERE state = 'free' ...
  ```
- now the trick is to include the state in the update, something like

  ```
   UPDATE queue SET state = 'processing' , updatedAt = ? 
   WHERE id = ? and state = 'free'
  ```

  Then check the number of modified rows. If it is 0, another worker did just pick the same row (and updated its state), and you just repeat the select to get another row.

If this is effective depends on the number of workers that try this at the same time (and would still profit from the index), and it is probably most useful if the "other conditions" are worker-dependent. If all workers would use the same row if available (e.g. always pick the oldest), not using "skip locked" would probably be faster.

And there are some other options. If you need help implementing a queue, you may want to ask another questions with your specific requirements.